# MailboxProcessor: Memory leak using return! before receive

Tags: f#

Given the following agent, which is a simple cache mechanism:

```
type CacheMsg<'a,'b> = Add of 'a * 'b | ForceFlush

type CacheAgent<'a, 'b when 'a : comparison>(size:int, flushCont:Map<'a, 'b> -> unit) =
    let agent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
        let rec loop (cache : Map<'a, 'b>) = async {
            let inline flush() =
                flushCont cache
                loop Map.empty

            if cache.Count > size then return! flush()

            let! msg = inbox.Receive()

            match msg with
            | Add (key, value) ->
                if cache.ContainsKey key then
                    return! loop cache
                else return! loop (cache.Add(key, value))
            | ForceFlush -> return! flush() }
        loop Map.empty)

    member x.AddIfNotExists key value = Add(key,value) |> agent.Post
    member x.ForceFlush() = agent.Post ForceFlush
```

This agent will keep taking up memory (seems like the memory is not freed when the `flushCont` has been called).

Given the same code, but with a minor change:

```
type CacheMsg<'a,'b> = Add of 'a * 'b | ForceFlush

type CacheAgent<'a, 'b when 'a : comparison>(size:int, flushCont:Map<'a, 'b> -> unit) =
    let agent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
        let rec loop (cache : Map<'a, 'b>) = async {
            let inline flush() =
                flushCont cache
                loop Map.empty

            let! msg = inbox.Receive()

            match msg with
            | Add (key, value) ->
                if cache.ContainsKey key then
                    return! loop cache
                else 
                    let newCache = cache.Add(key, value)
                    if newCache.Count > size then 
                        return! flush()
                    else return! loop (cache.Add(key, value))
            | ForceFlush -> return! flush() }
        loop Map.empty)

    member x.AddIfNotExists key value = Add(key,value) |> agent.Post
    member x.ForceFlush() = agent.Post ForceFlush
```

I have moved the expression that decides when to flush, into the union case `Add`. This results in the memory is freed as expected.

What's wrong about the first approach, since it leaks memory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first version isn't [tail recursive](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/07/08/tail-calls-in-fsharp.aspx).

It's not tail recursive, because this expression isn't the last expression in the function:

```
if cache.Count > size then return! flush()
```

After that expression, you call

```
let! msg = inbox.Receive()
```

so the `flush()` call isn't the last thing happening. After the recursive call implicit in `flush` has completed, the execution will need to return to the next expression, where you invoke `inbox.Receive()`. That means that the context will have to keep the previous invocation on the stack, because the recursion isn't in a tail position: there's still more work to do.

In the second example, all calls to `flush` and `loop` are in tail positions.

If you're coming from a C# background, you'd be inclined to think that `return! flush()` exits the function, but that's not really the case here. The only reason

```
if cache.Count > size then return! flush()
```

even compiles without a corresponding `else` branch is [because the expression returns `unit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233231.aspx). This means that the code inside the `then` branch doesn't truly exit the function - it just performs the work in the branch (in this case `flush()`), and then continues executing the subsequent expressions.